# Seleccionar casos en filas

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un caso en R. Mi data frame solo contiene un número de pórtico y patente de un auto, necesito separar mi df en dos, los autos que pasaron por el portico 1 y 2, y por otro lado los que solo pasaron por el 1 o por el 2.

```
portico   patente
1         A
2         A
1         B
2         B
1         C
```

Por ejemplo en este caso, los autos con patente A y B estarían dentro del primer grupo y C estaría en el segundo.

Answer (score 2):

Una alternativa sencilla usando R base podría ser:

```
casos <- aggregate(portico ~ patente, df, function(x) any(x==1) & any(x==2))
patentes_1y2 <- casos$patente[casos$portico]

df[df$patente %in% patentes_1y2,]
df[!(df$patente %in% patentes_1y2),]
```

Detalle:

- Mediante el `aggregate()` agrupamos por `patente` y `totalizamos` un `TRUE` si la `patente` tiene ambos `porticos`, generamos un vector `patentes_1y2`  únicamente con estos casos
- Luego seleccionamos las filas del `data.frame` original si la `patente` se encuentra o no en `patentes_1y2`

Answer (score 2):

Va una alternativa a la respuesta de @Patricio. La implemento con `dplyr`, pero se podría reformular para `base` o `data.table`. La idea es contar la cantidad de valores únicos de pórticos por grupo y ver si son `1` o más de `1`.

```
library(tidyverse)

tribble(~portico,   ~patente, 
               1,         "A",
               2,         "A",
               1,         "B",
               2,         "B",
               1,         "C") -> casos

casos %>% 
  group_by(patente) %>% 
  filter(length(unique(portico)) == 1) #Pasó por una o más veces por el mismo pórtico
  #filter(length(unique(portico)) > 1) #Pasó pasó por al menos dos pórticos diferentes
```

Esta opción funcionaría aún en el caso de un auto que pasó dos veces por el mismo pórtico, no es necesario pasarle "a mano" los nombres de pórticos y se puede adaptar para autos que pasaron por un número arbitrario de pórticos distintos. Podría no ser correcta si el caso se restringe a los pórticos 1 y 2, sin considerar un hipotético pórtico 3.